# What is the meaning of יוֹם (yowm) in Bereshit?

Tags: words, hebrew, time, parashat-bereishit, creation

I've heard conflicting reports of how the creation days' יוֹם (yowm), in Bereshit are interpreted in the Jewish community. How do actual Hebrew scholars define day in Bereshit? Six 24 hour periods or six long periods of time? Is one view favored over another(By Hebrew scholars), does each viewpoint have about equal support, or is there no argument?

Answer (score 12):

The 'catch all' meaning of the word 'yom' is 'time period'

The precise meaning of yom in tanach has 4 meanings depending on the context.

1. Either Yom as in daylight (12 hours)
2. Yom as a single day (24 hours)
3. Yom as a year or two (As used in shmuel and Yehoshua)
4. Yom can be an indefinite amount of time, such as the word 'b'yom meaning 'when, or the phrase 'Ad hayom hazeh' (until this day)

In Bereshit(Genesis) both the first and second meanings of the word are clearly used and the 4th meaning of the word is arguably used.  There is no single opinion agreed upon by everyone as to which meaning is used where.

It is agreed upon by everyone that the word 'Yom' is not used to mean the rising and setting of the sun however, because the sun was not placed in the sky to rise or set until the 4th yom.  (though 24 halachic hours is still the pshat, it's just not sun related halachic hours) And the Yom that is light, is defined in the first day.  This often leads to understandings that the light of the yom is a spiritual rather than physical light. (see Rashi)

The idea of a yom in bereshit being a very long period of time comes from tehilim, where it is written 'A day in your eyes is like one thousand years'.  This then question's as to who's perspective the creation story is told before Adam is created.

Comment: I figured that not everyone would agree with one interpretation, but part of my question is, how much agreement is there (Between those whose field of expertise is specifically the Hebrew language) with one way or the other or is it just evenly split. Also you did a very good job of describing the viewpoints, but what is your personal viewpoint? +1 thanks for the answer.

Comment: My personal viewpoint is that the question itself is too far away from the meaning and purpose of Torah study to be of real value :) When reading Rashi, I will understand it as 24 hours, when reading R. Aryeh Kaplan, I will understand it as epocs.

Comment: UserZer0, welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for bringing your question here! Please note that we deal primarily in objective answers, usually as found in authoritative sources, rather than in personal viewpoints.

Comment: Note also that your question is much more about literature than it is about linguistics. As avi established, this word means different things in different contexts, so the question really is what it means in this context, which is a question for those who are experts in the context - the Torah.

Comment: @Isaac To both your comments, yes, that's what I'm really looking for. Can you suggest a rewording that would convey this, or are you saying that there is no authoritative answer thus it shouldn't have a place here? Like I said, I've heard conflicting reports, some have said there is no real contention and others have claimed it's widely disputed, none of these claims that I've heard have come from a Jewish source, so that's why I'm asking here. But if I'm understanding the answers here, it looks like there isn't something that most people agree one way or the other?

Comment: @UserZer0, the question is perfectly appropriate here. There are indeed multiple definite answers given by various authorities.

Comment: @avi can you clarify your sentence "...4th meaning of the worse is arguably used." from the context I think you meant '4th meaning of the word', but it could also mean 'the 4th meaning is the worst one'. I'm not sure, I think you meant word?

Comment: Maybe a better example of the fourth meaning is all of the book of Devarim. The phrase "that I command you this day" is repeated literally dozens of times, but it is impossible that Moshe's speeches were said in one day; they clearly span the 37 or so days from 1 Shvat to the end of his life. "This day" certainly means, "at this time".

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: There are different opinions, each with their own proofs and backings.

Long answer:
Avi's answer explains the different meanings of "yom" quite well. It is my understanding that up until recently, *most* Rabbis agreed that in regard to creation, it meant a 24 hour period. Once scientists came up with theories about the age of the universe many Rabbis began to engage in what has been called "apologetics", explaining that "day" was metaphorical for "eras".

In my experience, whenever something in the Torah isn't meant literally, its always explained in the Talmud. The most famous example of something not meant literally is "an eye for an eye" which the Talmud says quite clearly (Bava Kamma, 83b-84a) that it refers to monetary compensation. There is no such explanation in the Talmud regarding "day" in Bereishis.

---

[You asked for personal opinions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10079/what-is-the-meaning-of-yowm-in-bereshit#comment14302_10083) so I'll say that I firmly believe that it was 24 hour periods. If it had meant anything else, certainly that would have been part of the oral tradition. Instead, the Rabbis in the Talmud explain what happened in each hour of the sixth day (Sanhedrin 38b). In addition, if it hadn't meant "days" literally, the Jewish observance of Shabbos as the seventh *day* of the week would be pretty meaningless. In fact, the entire concept of a seven day week would have no point. Also, the addition of "it was evening and it was morning, the _____ day" makes it quite clear to me that it was a "day" in the traditional meaning, albeit without the sun.

As a final point, the Lubavitcher Rebbe points out in a [letter](http://books.google.com/books?id=FmabnhsgSVAC&lpg=PR1&dq=mind%20over%20matter&pg=PA113#v=onepage&q&f=false) that there are those Rabbis who don't hold that the six days are literal, and therefore say that the world is older than 5771 years (as of this writing). For these Rabbis there is a serious problem with the text of the "get" or bill of divorce. Halacha is very stringent with the exact text of the bill ([here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/557971/jewish/Text-of-the-Get.htm) and [here](http://www.mazorguide.com/living/Divorce/GetText.htm)), because if the intended meaning is changed slightly - the bill is invalidated, the divorce is not valid, and any remarriage becomes adultery. On the bill of divorce, there must be written a date, and this date must be of the form - "Five thousand seven hundred and seventy one years according to the creation of the world according to our counting here". The Lubavitcher Rebbe points out that this would be contradicted by any interpretation of "days" being "epochs" or "eras".

Comment: The 'appologetics' began in the mideival period, when a desire to find 'sod' (secrets) in all of the Torah became prominent.  It predates any scientific findings.

Comment: Also, we keep shabbat because Gd tells us to in Shemot, not because of Bereshit.   Interesting point about a get.  But what does 'according to the creation' mean? What is the hebrew word there? (also I think you mean years, not days) Does it mean 'since' or does it mean 'by the authority of'? And does it mean 'creation of the world' or the book 'seder ha'olam'?

Comment: I did not preclude the possibility of earlier rabbis having that opinion. I would argue that it was not a mainstream idea until recently, though.

Comment: It's true that the commandment is in Shemos, but what was the reason given there? "because in six days G-d created the world, and on the seventh day he rested". The exact lashon of the Get is available at the links I posted. But the important quote is "blank years l'briyas haolam"-from the creation of the world.

Comment: Eh, not a very convincing argument.  the prefxi of lamed, can mean any of 4 different things. And in this context, it even spells out "לבריאת עולם למנין שאנו מנין ", that is, creation of the world that we calculate for our calendars. Which is true, no matter what the reality of the universe is or how you translate the word 'yom'

Comment: Yes, the lamed can mean several different things, none of which would change the meaning here, as far as I can tell. The phrase "לבריאת עולם למנין שאנו מנין " is actually a stronger proof to my main point, namely, that "our counting" i.e. the accepted age of the world (Halachically or colloquially, it doesn't matter to my point), accepts the interpretation of "yom" to mean "day". (As far as the Gets becoming void, you're right, that would probably prevent that, I'll change that part)

Comment: R' Slifkin, in Challenge of Creation, [quotes](http://books.google.com/books?id=cnNKtEhHJ9kC&lpg=PA181&dq=slifkin%20yom&pg=PA180#v=onepage&q&f=false) two different midrashim that seem to indicate that "Yom" in this context is different from 24 hours. He addresses the objections to this idea based on divorce documents and Shabbat there as well.

Comment: I don't follow the problem from Gittin. The count of 577X is from the end of the first chapter of Bereishit not the beginning. Otherwise you would have to change the year count on 25 Elul not 1 Tishrei. If so, then the number 577X is correct whether you hold of 6*24 hours or not.

Comment: What is the traditional meaning of morning without a sun? I didn't know we had a tradition about that.

Comment: @DoubleAA I recall seeing something about this once, but I don't recall what or where. However, one could even say that the Midrash R' Slifkin brings sheds some light: _"until this point (the sixth day) the counting was done relative to the universe; from this point on, a different system of counting commenced"_. One could say this refers to Solar days, as opposed to "universe days", but that the times of each were the same. <- Pure speculation.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, See above. Also, thank you for the link to R' Slifkin. I wonder how those who hold that the 6 days are literal would deal with those midrashim, particularly the one where the Midrash says G-d's "day" is a thousand years. Perhaps they would go the route of saying the _midrashim_ are allegorical, and the Chumash - literal.

Comment: @HodofHod Possibly, but at least we can say that neither read is just the simple text.

Comment: 'many Rabbis began to engage in what has been called "apologetics"' I don't see it as apologetics. When there was no reason to question the "24-hour pshat", that would be the default position. Once there is reason, the thing to do is look at what other explanations were available. - A similar example would be about "be'ei kinim", flea eggs, which the Talmud says there aren't any. I doubt anyone explained that they were microscopic until microscopes were invented. Afterwards, there are a number of explanations of the Talmud, but none suggests that our eyes are deceiving us.

Answer (score 0):

Although the Torah says the world was created in the six-days, we could understand them as six periods of time. See Babylonian Talmud, [Ketubot 57b](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.57b.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), where yamim (days) could mean years

Answer (score 0):

Or aChaim aKadosh answered this question.
There is a difference between HUMAN day and G-D's day!
Here what rabbi Atar wrote -
"Although G'd had said that Adam would die "on the day" he would eat from the tree of knowledge, the word "day" could have one of two connotations. It could mean a period of 24 hours, i.e. a day in human terms, or it could refer to a day in G'd's terms, i.e. 1000 years. If it is the latter, the meaning of the warning was that Adam would die before he reached the age of 1000 years. The respective connotation of the word depends on the severity of the sin and the feeling the sinner had at the time he committed the sin. If the sinner intended to anger G'd at the time he sinned, the meaning of the word "day" would be the minimum. The sinner would have to die before that period of 24 hours expired. If, however, the sin was not committed intentionally and the sinner had made it plain that he had not intended to sin, he would be given the maximum period possible, i.e. he would live up to but not including 1000 years."

Answer (score -2):

In Genesis 1:5, yom obviously means a regular day. Evening and morning is used, as well as a number.

Now if you look at Exodus 20:9-10 it says "6 days you shall labor and do all your work, but the seventh day is a Sabbath to Yhwh your God". Now yom here obviously means a regular, 24-hour day. But if you read on we'll see the reason for the Sabbath.

In Exodus 20:11 it says "For in six days Yhwh made the heavens and the earth, the sea, and all that is in them, but he rested on the seventh day. Therefore Yhwh blessed the Sabbath day and made it holy". Now the Sabbath would be meaningless if it was based on 6 indefinite time periods.

And also, this solves the problem with the "indefinite" period between Genesis 1:1,2 and Genesis 3. It says, "For in six days Yhwh made the heavens and the earth, the sea, and all that is in them". Plus, it says Yhwh created everything, therefore verifying that Genesis 1 and 2 are about the same creation.

When you look at the Hebrew bereshit, the first two words in Genesis, most translations say "in the beginning", but actually it means "in the beginning/start of". So if you literally translate the first verse in the Bible from Hebrew, it reads "In the beginning/start of God create the heavens and the earth," Now the Hebrew word for create is bara. You can't tell if it's past, present, or future. English versions always put it in the past tense, but a lot of Hebrew scholars think it is in the present. So therefore it would read, "in the beginning of God's creating of the heavens and the earth",

This makes much more sense, and it agrees with Exodus 20:21. And in Hebrew, Genesis 1:2 is clearly a description of when God was creating in Genesis 1:1. So the first two verses of Genesis should be, "In the beginning of God's creating of the heavens and the earth, when the earth was without form and void..."

This means that the universe is only around 6,000 years old.

Comment: As always, sources to support your claims would be invaluable. In particular in this case, since he is asking for opinions/statements of the "Hebrew scholars" with"in the Jewish community", I think this answer falls short of that standard. If you can supply some sources in the Jewish tradition to support your answer, I will undo my downvote.

Comment: Your biggest problem with this understanding, is that we define a day by the "rise" and "Setting" of the sun.  However, the Sun was not placed, to "rise and set" until Yom rivi.