# Does anyone explicitly say one may not believe in any type of evolution?

Tags: creation

As seen in the answers to [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15642/theology-on-evolution-from-khan-academy) Mi Yodea question, some Rabbis were fine with accepting at least some version of the theory of evolution. [A belief in God's involvement in the process seems to be a prerequisite.]

I am curious though, are there or were there any Rabbis who were vocally opposed to accepting any version this theory whatsoever?

(Written sources which can be checked inside are preferable.)

Comment: Are we looking at a specific time frame for this? I guess by definition we're looking for rabbis post publication of Darwin who voiced opposition to the theory?

Comment: I think the theory may have existed a little before Darwin. His chidush was the whole survival of the fittest. I think. But in theory, yes this would have to be someone from the last couple hundred years. Also, I don't want carbon dating mixed into this question. That is a different subject. I am currently looking specifically for discussions on evolution. And in this question I seek the naysayers.

Comment: Rav Hirsch predicated acceptance on a requisite degree of evidence. If one thinks that the current evidence does not suffice, then Rav Hirsch would not consider it.

Comment: The topic matter precludes all sources until the last couple of centuries, so that that limits the pool of sources and the expected authority of those discussing it. That being said, R. Dr. Meiselman frames it an inappropriate belief in his _Torah Chazal and Science_. (Please do not use this as an opportunity to discuss the quality of the book. That is irrelevant to the question of whether any rabbis write that the view is unacceptable; right or wrong, it is written).

Comment: The evolution theory contains 2 supposed facts: changing in species with time to more adapted kinds; a randomal spectrum of mutations that results in the survivance of the more adaptated. The Jewish Emuna concern a creator that directed the creation. A end of creation "ויכל אלוקים". So two problems are dealed with evolution. Evolution before "ויכל אלוקים" and evolution after "ויכל אלוקים". The first is not necessary a problem. The second needs explanations. Each Rabbi can  explain how he wants. The important is where are problems

Comment: @mevaqesh I wouldn't do that. I haven't dismissed him as a mon diamar ch'v. My comment way back when about the book was about my own personal appreciation of it. How it appeals to me, not what I think it's worth. I would appreciate and up-votes an answer from there fwiw. And if you choose not to write one up, let me at least thank you for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: @user6591 I did indeed remember your comment. However, my last comment was addressed primarily at the comment section in general, trying to keep it on topic.

Comment: @user6591 I had a speaker in high school brought in to explain why Evolution was garbage. Tbh I didn't find out until later it was a viable theory in Judaism.

Comment: @Orion Yeah. I think many if not most schools and pulpit rabbis preach the non evolution route. That's part of my motivation here. To see if there are any real sources to justify that approach, or not. Maybe they all just got caught up in the Christian literalist point of view. There was a michtav me'eliyahu where he mentioned his logical problems with the theory. But he didn't go on to say it was an irreligious view.

Comment: @user6591 so if you know of pulpit and school rabbis then I assume you're question is looking for more well known Rabbis AND their stated reasoning. Is that right? Maybe edit in what kind of Rabbis you're talking about.

Comment: @Orion Well I requested written sources in parenthesis, and I assume people aren't just going to post that a Rabbi who nobody ever heard of says so.