# Arguments against evolution

Tags: parashat-bereishit, science, creation, biology

In trying to find the best, most factually based argument against evolution, I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dZlSL5_LYV8) which said that it just doesn't make sense because why would a creator take so long.

Are there any other factual / logical proofs from reliable Jewish sources that easily disprove evolution?

Comment: Genesis 1 do you rely on the Torah for facts?

Comment: Not sure this is on topic

Comment: I give an argument at [Creationism and Evolution](https://sabbahillel.blogspot.com/2011/10/breishis-creationism-and-evolutionism.html) where I show that both sides often miss the point.

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel I've heard people say that before, but it doesn't make sense to me.  Can you open up Mishpatim and derive all of Bava Kamma without looking at a Gemara or Mechilta?  If not, why do you expect to be able to open up Bereishis and derive all of science?

Comment: @Heshy Simply put, I just meant that it speaks of creating the man. Not sure if that addresses your points, which I am inclined to concur with.

Comment: You could why G-d took His time in creation. Rambam says it was probably instantaneous. Indeed one could ask is the moon designed? This argument only holds true (up) if G-d designed the universe. I believe G-d created the world (including the moon, stars, and sun) and ordered them throughout the rest of the time to act accordingly with the laws of nature. Yes. G-d created the moon.

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Why can’t evolution be the mechanism by which Hashem created man?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Theology on evolution from khan academy](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15642/theology-on-evolution-from-khan-academy)

Comment: @DonielF It certainly can be. God could even make a very heavy rock. I just don’t have any Rabbinical backing for it.

Comment: Is that you in the linked video?

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is fair to suggest, though I naturally cannot provide a "source", that if there where "sources that easily disprove evolution" then someone who is introduced to the controversy would likely have encountered them because opponents of evolution would give preference to such arguments. Furthermore, I am not sure it is reasonable to presume that a dominant scientific paradigm can be "easily" disproven even if it where incorrect.  It is dominant for a reason.

Additionally, while we could (but shouldn't) have a whole discussion of how to use terminology, a discussion of "factual based arguments", which I would take to best apply to material or concrete evidence, would be off topic here. Any way in which this question  is relevantly addressed *here* would be philosophical/theological in nature as would be the arguments.

It is also worthwhile to be aware that throughout the Orthodox world many, if not most, do not believe the Theory of Evolution is incorrect or problematic.  While there is a [traditional preference for preserving the literal interpretation of Scriptures](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/30000/899) there are plenty who do not in this case and are not without some measure of support in doing so. It is worthwhile not to beg this question in a forum such as this.

Finally, and more to the point, the very notion of Creation יש מאין as described in [Genesis implies a world that would have appeared to have had prior existence of both the material and the processes which typically created them.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/697/899) There is not necessarily reason to "disprove" processes which are said to have transpired prior to this point. To be certain, difficult questions remain, but probably not more difficult than uprooting a centerpiece of modern science.

Comment: Yirmeyahu, good answer. I would add that evolution, as a fact, would be hard to disprove, yet, I think you answered this well.

Comment: Also, I agree with you that G-d created the world out of preexisting matter, as matter cannot be created or destroyed, it follows, that matter always existed and G-d merely manipulated it to create the world.

Comment: @TurkHill Thank you for your compliment but I must note that this answer doesn't address my personal opinion and it also discusses Creation יש מאין, not Creation יש מיש.