# How do we reconcile the order of creating animals betweeen Genesis and science?

Tags: animals, science, parashat-bereishit, creation

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6932/does-the-torah-encoded-age-of-the-universe-match-science#comment53788_6932

> The Genesis 1 creation account conflicts with the order of events that are known to science. In Genesis, the earth is created before
>   light and stars, birds and whales before reptiles and insects, and
>   flowering plants before any animals. The order of events known from
>   science is just the opposite

[This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30/bereishit-vs-science) is about the cosmic events (stars, planets, etc).  The current question is about the animals.

I checked the bible again

> 20 And God said, “Let the water teem with living creatures, and let
>   birds fly above the earth across the vault of the sky.” 21 So God
>   created the great creatures of the sea and every living thing with
>   which the water teems and that moves about in it, according to their
>   kinds, and every winged bird according to its kind. And God saw that
>   it was good. 22 God blessed them and said, “Be fruitful and increase
>   in number and fill the water in the seas, and let the birds increase
>   on the earth.” 23 And there was evening, and there was morning—the
>   fifth day.
>
> 24 And God said, “Let the land produce living creatures according to
>   their kinds: the livestock, the creatures that move along the ground,
>   and the wild animals, each according to its kind.” And it was so. 25
>   God made the wild animals according to their kinds, the livestock
>   according to their kinds, and all the creatures that move along the
>   ground according to their kinds. And God saw that it was good.
>
> 26 Then God said, “Let us make mankind in our image, in our likeness,
>   so that they may rule over the fish in the sea and the birds in the
>   sky, over the livestock and all the wild animals,[a] and over all the
>   creatures that move along the ground.”

So according to bible, birds are created before land animals (like reptiles). Science says that reptiles are are around before birds. Birds evolve out of reptiles.

How do we reconcile this?

I could match that ground animals mean mammals but that's pretty much stretching it. I could think that fish indeed show up first, and they are keep evolving even after the animals are being created. However, birds are descendants of ground reptiles.

So science says the sequence seems to be

1. fishes
2. reptiles (including ground reptiles)
3. birds
4. mammals

while Genesis says the sequence is

1. fishes and birds (day 5)
2. ground reptiles and mammals

Hmm... almost a match but not quite.

Comment: This is not duplicate. I am not asking the discrepancy in general. I am asking the sequences of animals.

Comment: If you edit to make it more clearly about the animals, including in the title, we can reopen.  (Also, you should cast this as why Genesis and science disagree, not why Genesis says something different than "what happened".  Your wording implies that the torah account can't be what happened, but that's not a given here.)

Comment: I am not saying that the torah account can't be what happened (it depends on how we interpret it). I am saying that the scientific theory is so strong there is no way it doesn't happen that way.

Comment: I think you presumed that I think "hence" the torah must be wrong. No. I am open minded here. I mean how do we reconcile literally. I am impressed that a 5k years old book can get something "almost correct". But we need to go more than almost for God claims right?

Comment: Well, your original title was about Genesis versus "what happened", which suggests you see a conflict there.  I'm going to make a few more edits to your question and then reopen.

Comment: And Genesis 2 says the order is heaven & earth, rain, man, herbs and trees, land animals, birds, woman.

Comment: This question, as currently stated, is weak, since it ascribes a position to Science without documenting it.

Comment: _known to science_ -- Science doesn't really "know" anything. Science can predict that coins dropped on a table will usually land on one of the faces, based on multiple previous dropped coins; science can also suggest that a heap (i.e. not a precise stack) of coins face-up or face-down arrived on the table by being dropped. However, I can certainly have more direct knowledge of the events in question -- e.g. I see someone artfully arranging the coins as if they were dropped, or I am told that this is what happened by a trustworthy source.

Comment: creation cannot be detected by science. two different systems

Comment: Where in science is there a theory that there were plants before the sun and the moon? W

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Rambam says that the details of the chapter of the Creation (I suppose, Gen. 1 and 2) should not be taught to the masses lest they misunderstand or twist what it means (Guide to the Perplexed, 2:17). An implication may perhaps be drawn that the literal reading is not all that there is to the story of Creation and that, perhaps, it should not be taken as literal 24 hour days. It may not be discussing chronological order of physical creation but rather a more mystical discussion of the order of potential for creation. Some commentators say that the potential for everything was created in the six days, but it wasn't  until the events in Genesis 2 that their reality was realized. And that reality might have been realized in a nature-veiled setting of 4.5 billion years of Earth, from guiding conditions for the first life to form until the desired present-day beings exist, all from a seemingly natural history.

Comment: When did Rabam lives?

Comment: @Jim Thio 12th century.

Comment: And he said that long before Darwin... Hmmm... Impressive. What's his reasoning? That it doesn't make sense?

Comment: @JimThio I doubt the Rambam believed in common descent. However his words could be understood to mean that he wouldn't rule it out either.

Comment: Nahmanides makes a similar point in the beginning of Genesis

Comment: Where does the Rambam write this?

Comment: @BabySeal My understanding of Nahmanides there was that the deeper lessons are about spiritual creation and do not take away from the physical creation. In his case, I wouldn't infer from Nahmanides's words that the 6 days could be understood as anything other than the literal 24 hour days, since he explicitly says that they were literal 24 hour days. (Even for Rambam, I don't think the loose interpretation would really set well, but I was just suggesting that there is a possibility he would be *okay* with such a reinterpretation.)

Comment: Hi. This is an incorrect understanding of Rambam. Saying creation is anything more than 6 sets of 24 hours contradicts the entire commandant of Shabbos.

Answer (score 8):

This question was the root of an argument between [Dr. Gerald Schroeder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerald_Schroeder) and [Rabbi Natan Slifkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natan_Slifkin). Dr. Schroeder insists (in his book [Genesis and the Big Bang](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0553354132), and in many public lectures) that the order of creation in the Torah is meant to be taken chronologically and is correct. He explained the flying creatures which existed before the land animals to be referring to certain species of winged insects which existed before land dwellers evolved (I don't know enough science to evaluate the veracity of that claim).

Rabbi Slifkin was bothered that, aside from it not being the straightforward implication of the text, this leaves the creation of actual birds absent - if the mention of "birds" on day 5 was insects, then actual birds were left out. Rabbi Slifkin instead proposed (in The Science of Torah, later revised into [The Challenge of Creation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9652295949)) that the order of the days of creation is not meant to be taken as an actual chronological order, and that the Torah is merely just referring to "powers" of creation.

Rabbi Slifkin's approach sparked a raging debate in the Orthodox world, which I don't want to get into but am only mentioning as a way of pointing out that his approach was not by any means universally accepted.

Answer (score 4):

Who says they must be reconciled?

God can create a one day old tree with rings.

Or stars millions of light years away with the light reaching here immediately.

also, evolution is just a theory. in my opinion it takes ALOT of FAITH to believe that life forms can evolve from inorganic molecules.

consider a upgrading windows XP to windows 8, something far less complex than upgrading a fish to the simplest flying bird or a three chambered heart to a four chambered heart. now type some random letters in the windows XP code.
Is it possible that through trial and error you can upgrade the code? remember evolution must be advantageous each tiny step. Big changes are not possible through random mutations due to complexity.

yet, you'd need big complex changes to upgrade things since lines of code are all interdependent. changes must be coordinated with lots of other changes.
there's a limit to what trial and error can accomplish in something like this

I recommend you check out the book "Not by Chance" by MIT Physicist Dr.Spetner

UPDATE: I found an article which explains in more details this fatal flaw in evolution. see: http://theoligarch.com/richard-dawkins-aliens.htm

Regarding the below comment, Gravity is not theoretical, gravity is proven and actual. Nobody can doubt its existence. If you want to test it, try jumping off something. On the other hand, evolution even after 100 years of research remains theoretical - it has not been proven. On the contrary, the more research is done, the more doubt on its validity as the above link shows.

Comment: Gravity is also just a theory. I recommend you check out all the works of Ivy League scientists who endorse evolution.

Comment: In any event, you just proposed a reconciliation. You suggested that the universe was created looking exactly as if it were billions of years old. So from a scientific perspective (ie figuring out how nature works) we are fully justified in treating the world as billions of years old, and making experiments and drawing conclusions based on that, because the world looks and behaves exactly as a billion year old world would. So who needs them to be reconciled? Apparently you do.

Comment: Look at free market. Imagine a government trying to create microsoft, apples. It won't work. But let to evolve by themselves under great system, great things happen.

Comment: see http://creation.com/not-by-chance I read the book. very worthwhile reading. I Also have a degree in physics so can appreciate his treatise

Comment: @good_ole_ray Do you have a degree in philosophy of science, that you can understand critiques of the epistemic and ontic issues surrounding scientific theories?

Comment: Your recent edits answer my previous comment clearly in the negative. Perhaps you should look into that field before you go telling others what a [scientific theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_theory) is.

Comment: there's a clear distinction between the theory of gravity and the theory of evolution. gravity is actual and proven, evilution remains theoretical. you're using semantics to instigate trouble.

Comment: Either I'm using semantics to instigate trouble, or you have trouble using words to communicate. If you have an idea, a point, a distinction or a thought to contribute, express it clearly and explicitly using accepted and precise language.

Comment: You are conflating the theory of evolution, with specific theories on the origin of life. See e.g. https://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/misconceptions_faq.php#a1

Answer (score 4):

It occured to me while reading the [Gen 1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0101.htm), that reptiles may be implied by the verses.

First check out [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/38778/4682). The exegetical approach used therein is the one I am attempting to use.

Next, note the wording of verse 20, when water life and flying things are introduced:

> וַיֹּאמֶר אֱלֹהִים--**יִשְׁרְצוּ הַמַּיִם, שֶׁרֶץ נֶפֶשׁ חַיָּה**; וְעוֹף יְעוֹפֵף עַל-הָאָרֶץ, עַל-פְּנֵי רְקִיעַ הַשָּׁמָיִם.
>
> And God said: '**Let the waters swarm with swarms of living creatures**, and let fowl fly above the earth in the open firmament of heaven.'

And then in verse 21:

> וַיִּבְרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֶת-הַתַּנִּינִם הַגְּדֹלִים; **וְאֵת כָּל-נֶפֶשׁ הַחַיָּה הָרֹמֶשֶׂת** אֲשֶׁר שָׁרְצוּ הַמַּיִם לְמִינֵהֶם, וְאֵת כָּל-עוֹף כָּנָף לְמִינֵהוּ, וַיַּרְא אֱלֹהִים, כִּי-טוֹב.
>
> And God created the great sea-monsters, and **every living creature that creepeth/ moveth**, that the waters swarmed, after its kind, and every winged fowl after its kind; and God saw that it was good.

The creeping things were not mentioned from the outset. This is as opposed to day 6:

> וַיֹּאמֶר אֱלֹהִים, תּוֹצֵא הָאָרֶץ נֶפֶשׁ חַיָּה לְמִינָהּ, בְּהֵמָה **וָרֶמֶשׂ** וְחַיְתוֹ-אֶרֶץ, לְמִינָהּ; וַיְהִי-כֵן.
>
> And God said: 'Let the earth bring forth the living creature after its kind, cattle, and **creeping thing**, and beast of the earth after its kind.' And it was so.
>
> וַיַּעַשׂ אֱלֹהִים אֶת-חַיַּת הָאָרֶץ לְמִינָהּ, וְאֶת-הַבְּהֵמָה לְמִינָהּ, **וְאֵת כָּל-רֶמֶשׂ הָאֲדָמָה**, לְמִינֵהוּ; וַיַּרְא אֱלֹהִים, כִּי-טוֹב.
>
> And God made the beast of the earth after its kind, and the cattle after their kind, and **every thing that creepeth upon the ground** after its kind; and God saw that it was good

also note a [distinctive](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/c/hr/tables.htm#dis21) *pazer* mark [above הָרֹמֶשֶׂת](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=42), which separates the phrase "and all the creeping things" From "That the waters swarmed".

Verse 21 could very well have read as follows:

> וַיִּבְרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֶת-הַתַּנִּינִם הַגְּדֹלִים; וְאֵת אֲשֶׁר שָׁרְצוּ הַמַּיִם לְמִינֵהֶם, וְאֵת כָּל-עוֹף כָּנָף לְמִינֵהוּ, וַיַּרְא אֱלֹהִים, כִּי-טוֹב.
>
> And God created the great sea-monsters, and that which the waters brought forth, after its kind, and every winged fowl after its kind; and God saw that it was good.

שרצו‏ is translated by Onkelos as ארחישו‏, which can mean to bring forth, ([look it up!](http://www.tyndalearchive.com/tabs/jastrow/))

Thus I assert that the phrase וְאֵת כָּל-נֶפֶשׁ הַחַיָּה הָרֹמֶשֶׂת, refers to other crawling things, those that came most directly from water, (hence the juxtaposition), namely land reptiles.

And should you say, let the verse say "**and** that which the waters brought forth", here the verse tells of the actual creation of water life. By the actual creation of land creatures, (**verse 25**). it also mentions רמש‏ and it is separate from other types of animals. Just as it is separate there, it is separate here.

Also, note the phrase נֶפֶשׁ הַחַיָּה, living creature, that is used in verse 20 and 24, when introducing new life forms. This same phrase is present in verse 21, on our creeping things, suggesting a new distinct life form. see verse 25 on day where the phrase is not used when the creative process is described. Just as those refer to new life forms, so does this.

**The obvious question**, of course, is why crawling things are mentioned both on day 5 and on day 6. To that question I would say that there are indeed many crawling things, such as rodents or insects, that are in a different category of crawling things than land reptiles, (land reptiles being more closely related to amphibians and to water life), that are meant by the mention on day 6.

**Alternatively,**

The verse, even read simply, as is, could imply that the water brought forth crawling things that crawled on the land. Note that birds are mentioned last by the verse.

The the verse would mean:

> And God created the great sea-monsters, and every living creature that creepeth, that the waters brought forth, (*meaning both things that are still in the water, and things that went on to the land, directly from water*), after its kind, and every winged fowl after its kind; and God saw that it was good.

So perhaps we can say that the verse alludes to crawling things that came forth from the water and became birds, land reptiles.

**Lastly**, I think it is poignant that God blesses water life on day 5, but not life on day 6. See verse 22. The next blessing is given to man in verse 28. Is land life not blessed?

Perhaps we can say that Land life, and in fact all life, originating from water, (except plants), was *already* blessed by God, in verse 22, so further blessing would have been redundant.

**And** one last thought, the name of the cantillation mark I mentioned above, the *pazer*, פזר‏, means disperse, which perhaps hints at a dispersal of species from water!

<sup>Dr. Schroeder, Rabbi Slifkin, and a baby seal?! :D</sup>

Answer (score 3):

According to [Rashi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi)'s commentary on Genesis, the order of events presented therein is *not* to be taken literally.

He concludes a long comment on [1:1](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8165#showrashi=true&v=1) with:

> על כרחך לא לימד המקרא סדר המוקדמים והמאוחרים כלום
>
> Perforce, you must admit that Scripture did not teach us anything about the sequence of the earlier and the later [acts of creation].

He backs this claim up by citing certain difficulties that would be presented if we assume that the Scriptural account does teach us the sequence of events. One is that the first creation mentioned, "the heavens," are in turn a product of fire and water, neither of which was previously mentioned as having been created. Another is that water is mentioned explicitly in [1:2](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8165#showrashi=true&v=2), but again, is not listed previously as having been created.

Later, on [1:14](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8165#showrashi=true&v=14), which reports the creation of the luminaries of the heavens, Rashi comments that they, along with all of the other items mentioned in the Creation account, were actually created on the first day, and just subsequently arranged.

> מיום ראשון נבראו, וברביעי צוה עליהם להתלות ברקיע, וכן כל תולדות שמים וארץ נבראו מיום ראשון, וכל אחד ואחד נקבע ביום שנגזר עליו, הוא שכתוב (פסוק א) את השמים, לרבות תולדותיהם, ואת הארץ, לרבות תולדותיה
>
> They were created on the first day, and on the fourth day, He commanded them to be suspended in the sky, and likewise, all the creations of heaven and earth were created on the first day, and each one was fixed in its proper place on the day that was decreed upon it. That is why it is written: "with the heavens (אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם)" to include their products, "and with the earth (וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ)," to include its products.

So, it turns out that according to [the tradition transmitted by] Rashi, the actual creation of all things took place before the day-by-day account described in Genesis 1, with a sequence not reported in the Torah at all. Genesis 1 recounts these items being "fixed into place," but it is not at all obvious what that means, given that they were created already.

With the actual sequence of creation now off the Scriptural table, there's no way to impeach it with observed evidence.

Comment: That was referring to the first verse only

Comment: @YakkOv I don't understand your comment. The first comment of Rashi that I cited explicitly deals with verses other than the first one, and the second comment that I cited deals directly with 1:14

Comment: Talking about the first verse. The "out of sequence" is only regarding that. The fact that everything was made the first day and later placed in position on the other days is of no consequence to the order the other things were made (mentioned in places other than the first verse). For example, to say light and dark was made not in the first day isn't "off the table". To say birds weren't made in the fifth day isn't "off the table", even though they were all created in a general way on day 1

Answer (score 2):

The verse's words read as follows:

> *And God said: 'Let the waters swarm with swarms of living creatures, and let fowl fly above the earth in the open firmament of heaven.'*

One could argue that there is an implication of the sea creatures finding their way on to land and eventually becoming birds. The only thing missing is the transitional species.

I don't think it is unreasonable to say that Gd only mentioned the species of creatures that were extant at the time of Adam's creation. So the transitional forms from amphibians to reptiles to birds, being extinct by the time of Adam's creation, were not mentioned at all.

Answer (score 1):

First note that there is a grouping of animals into sea, air and land animals

This is part of the paralleling between "days" 1-3 and 4-6 of creation. The first 3 days describe the creation of the infrastructures and the next 3 days describe the "hosts", the things that fill and realize those infrastructures:

light/darkness    ||  sea/sky || land (with vegetation)

luminaries  ||  fish/birds  || land animals

(Cassuto on Genesis)

This paralleling entails a) grouping all land animals together and b) describing them on day 6, in parallel to day 3.

In addressing man, the Torah grouped the less important ground reptiles with the more important livestock.

Indeed, livestock (cows, sheep,etc) evolved after birds.

Comment: How do you know any species evolved from any other species, and weren't simply all created fully formed?

Answer (score 1):

B"H

**How do we reconcile the order of creating animals betweeen Genesis and science?**

Expanding on [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/25846/31763):

Like many questions, the answer can be found in the question itself.

"Science" is not one person or one ideology that one "reconciles" with.

It is the current understanding of humans based on the information they have.

[Official definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/science):

> knowledge or a system of knowledge covering general truths or the
> operation of general laws especially as obtained and tested through
> scientific method

So according to their definition, no one truly knows any "science" unless they know every detail of existence, but they can amas some bits and pieces of "science" through what they know.

The only one who knows everything is the Creator of Heavens and Earth.

The science that humans know changes with humans' understanding.

What was scientifically thought to be true 50 years ago might not be the same as it is now, and according to them, what they think was true 1000 years ago might not be either

(Except, not necessarily...)

The point is, according to their understanding, it's always changing, because human understanding is always changing.

The Creator never changes; thus, everything He said, even thousands of years ago, is completely true now, since He knows everything.

(Especially since Hashem is giving the Torah anew every instant, "Giver of the Torah", and "every day a voice emanates from Mount Chorev", see ד"ה אנכי תשמ"ט)

The specific question was:

> So according to bible, birds are created before land animals (like
> reptiles). Science says that reptiles are are around before birds.
> Birds evolve out of reptiles.

The answer to the question is in the question.

According to the word of the Creator, birds were **created** before reptiles. The question assumes "being around" and "evolution"...

The creation of the birds and all species happened in a completely miraculous way, just like all other parts of creation.

Rashi tells us that they all miraculously were created from the ground, fully grown and fully alive at the time they were created, each day being 24 hours

(Btw, 24 hours is a *huge* amount of time for creation to take place, considering that Hashem could simply think everything into existence instantaneously. In fact, the difference between the smallest unit of time (instantaneous) relative to 6 × 24 hours, is much greater than the difference between 6 × 24 hours and 14 billion years)

There's no hint of species evolving from each other in the Torah..

If one says that Hashem caused evolution to happen, then that would be:

Completely illogical, since Hashem deliberately taking 24 hours to miraculously form the species from the ground is already way more than He needs to, to say He stretched the process out over millions of years through "natural processes" would not only be unnecessary, but illogical, and

There's no Torah source for such an idea in any universally accepted sources, no Rishonim, no Midrashim etc. The only people who are saying it are those who try to change the simple meaning of the Torah according to the current, limited understanding of some modern day scientists.

If one says that Hashem created the "big bang", then the creation of one single atom/whatever the big bang was supposed to be from, from completely nothing, is an infinitely greater novelty than creating already living species from already existing dust.

At a certain point, one has to choose between what modern scientists say, and what the Torah says.

Just ask yourself: if it was certain to you that you had to choose one or the other, which one would it be?

See also the [Rebbe's explanation of the Torah and the age of the universe (which also discusses evolution)](https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/letters/default_cdo/aid/1890858/jewish/The-Age-of-the-Universe.htm).

To quote a relevant part:

> We may now summarize the weaknesses, nay, hopelessness, of all
> so-called scientific theories regarding the origin and age of our
> universe:
>
> (a) These theories have been advanced on the basis of observable data
> during a relatively short period of time, of only a number of decades,
> and at any rate not more than a couple of centuries.
>
> (b) On the basis of such a relatively small range of known (though by
> no means perfectly) data, scientists venture to build theories by the
> weak method of extrapolation, and from the consequent to the
> antecedent, extending to many thousands (according to them, to
> millions and billions) of years!
>
> (c) In advancing such theories, they blithely disregard factors
> universally admitted by all scientists, namely, that in the initial
> period of the birth of the universe, conditions of temperature,
> atmospheric pressure, radioactivity, and a host of other cataclystic
> factors, were totally different from those existing in the present
> state of the universe.
>
> (d) The consensus of scientific opinion is that there must have been
> many radioactive elements in the initial stage which now no longer
> exist, or exist only in minimal quantities; some of them - elements
> that cataclystic potency of which is known even in minimal doses.
>
> (e) The formation of the world, if we are to accept these theories,
> began with a process of colligation (of binding together) of single
> atoms or the components of the atom and their conglomeration and
> consolidation, involving totally unknown processes and variables.
>
> In short, of all the weak scientific theories, those which deal with
> the origin of the cosmos and with its dating are (admittedly by the
> scientists themselves) the weakest of the weak.
>
> It is small wonder (and this, incidentally, is one of the obvious
> refutations of these theories) that the various scientific theories
> concerning the age of the universe not only contradict each other, but
> some of them are quite incompatible and mutually exclusive, since the
> maximum date of one theory is less than the minimum date of another.
>
> If anyone accepts such a theory uncritically, it can only lead him
> into fallacious and inconsequential reasoning. Consider, for example,
> the so-called evolutionary theory of the origin of the world, which is
> based on the assumption that the universe evolved out of existing
> atomic and subatomic particles which, by an evolutionary process,
> combined to form the physical universe and our planet, on which
> organic life somehow developed also by an evolutionary process, until
> homo-sapiens emerged. It is hard to understand why one should readily
> accept the creation of atomic and subatomic particles in a state which
> is admittedly unknowable and inconceivable, yet should be reluctant to
> accept the creation of planets, or organisms, or a human being, as we
> know these to exist.

He then continues to discuss why fossil "evidence" isn't valid, see there.

Answer (score 1):

re the bird and dino origins and chronology disputed science:
avian founding kinds (70 +/-+)  were created mid day 5 just hours prior to dino founding kinds (10 +/- ). Define dino as within the 'Tanin Gadol' founding kinds.
So include upright with legs underneath reptiles, from which modern reptiles speciated, adapted and / or devolved from.
Now birds and bats.. founding kinds were represented on the ark of Noach, while implicit dinos not on the passenger list.
so a scientist that did not take that into account might assume all these birds during The ice ages, and the absence of dinos during The ice ages and maybe the dinos 'evolved' into birds, which is cartoon like imaginative.
Aside from the genetics, the fossil record we find fully complex birds in the same strata as dinos. so birds and dinos co-existed, prior to The 1656 anno mundi Mabul.
reference Pearlman YeC for the alignment of Torah testimony, science and ancient civ.

Answer (score 0):

Science proves nothing concrete re: creation because no scientist was there to observe, repeat, falsify. If you examine fossils you find that there is not a strict order of their appearance worldwide. It appears a lot of water was instrumental in drowning a lot of living things including plants - not strictly in accordance with text books.

Suggest each one who has an opinion do a detailed and scientific study on this. I took several years out of my life to do this, and even as a layman, can conclude that the biblical account taken as written is very feasible.

BTW, Genesis chapter two does not conflict with one. Two begins when the earth had not yet sprouted plants briefly established that point in time, then jumps over to day 6 when God created man. Then God creates more plants for the Garden in Eden on that day 6, (there is no mandate that He could not do that additional creation of plants and trees and the Hebrew text reads that way - for it was not yet day 7 when He rested from all creation). Whereupon, the text reads that God also created ADDITIONAL birds and beasts of the field again no mandate that He could not do this. Nothing in the text says that God compartmentalized certain categories of living beings such that He could not / would not create some more of the same at a later time! Then God created woman on the 6th day. Then He rested on the 7th day. See no conflict.

I've posted this here: http://www.biblestudymanuals.net/gen2_observe.htm

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to get over this question myself, but at some point you have to realise that they do not need to be reconciled. Science is humans looking at the world in the present and trying to figure out how it works, and what happened in the past through inference.

The first of the ikarim is that Hashem created and *controls* everything. He even controls the unfolding of scientific discovery.

Torah is Hashem telling us about Himself, and His side of the story.

A mashal given is a scientist finds a table and tries to work out what it is, what it's for, what it's made from. He comes up with a theory. But then walks in the carpenter who made the table. If the carpenter tells him that he made the table out of mahogany wood, but the scientist had concluded oak, the scientist would never say "well, you are wrong, my mass spectrometer has confirmed with a margin of error of 5% that this is oak".

So why should we try to reconcile the two?

It is none-the-less interesting and I heard in yeshiva from Rav Dovid Gottlieb that the chachamim have "ruled" that the world was created 5783 years ago, not 13.7 billion. If you don't like that, go find some other chachamim, or whatever.

The real question is, what is more romantic:

1. Hashem's goal was so awesome that He was willing to wait 13.7 billion years to see it through
2. Hashem's goal was so awesome, He didn't want to waste a second and built it in as short a time as made sense in his calculations (which turns out to be 7 days k'negged the 7 middot)

I think each person these days has a preference and will seek the answers that match that preference, and as you've seen from all the answers here, there is some sort of answer for every possiblity with some sort of "reliable" source.

Comment: There are halachic nafka minas from exactly how you go about it.  Kashrus of frozen wooly mammoth meat is a fun one.  Tumah of frozen humans dated to more than 6000 years ago is another, and there are three options (meis, neveilah, tahor) that are each supported by different Bereishis-science sources.  These cases are a bit exotic but no less real than any other halachic question, and I think you'll agree that leaving it down to personal "preference" is not an option in halacha.

Comment: @dov lol will you edit this answer every year?

Comment: @heshy nothing is dated more than 5783 years

Comment: Waiting 6×24 hours is much more of a novelty than waiting 14 billion years, considering he could has be made it all in an instant

Comment: @Heshy I totally agree, but that's the point. There are different opinions, by different factions, each claiming that they are authority (or that the other side is not authority). So the end result is that people pick based on their preference. If you ever are wondering if you should eat that mammoth meat, check the authority that represents your minhag.

Comment: @dov can you edit the title of the question please, it's bugging me

Comment: @YakkOv of course things are dated to more than 5783 years ago.  You can argue that those dating systems are wrong, but not that they don't exist.

Comment: @Heshy another argument is that Hashem created an "old" world, as does the Lubavitcher Rebbe. Either way, I think YakkOv is talking in a halachic context

Comment: @RabbiKaii I know (btw I've always wanted to meet a Chabadnik who eats mammoth meat).  The point is the _question_ relates to bodies that scientists date to 5783 years old.  I'm not presupposing any answer.

Comment: If the world is created old, then it's even more complicated about the mammoth meat! I would take issue that only Chabadniks need to take R' Schneerson's rulings seriously, in the same way that I wouldn't expect a sefardi to never learn mishna brura.

Comment: @heshy if they're not correct, then they don't truly exist. Falsehood has no "feet". Only that which is true can be said to "exist"; that which is false is only an imaginary existence, at best.