# Noach's deluge: local, but referred to as everywhere

Tags: geography, parashat-noach, mabul

Some try to [reconcile Noach's story with the fact that the Chinese (and other cultures like the Native Americans) existed beforehand and afterwards (with documented history) and didn't die](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28441) by saying that the Mabul only happened in Mesopotamia. Then how come the Torah speaks of it as the destruction of the world (end of ALL living)?

Comment: Izzy, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for the interesting questions! But the first was a duplicate of [an already-asked-and-answered question](/q/28441): lucky you, you get ready-made answers! So I've edited it out of this post. And the last (about the water) seems like a completely separate point, so I've removed it; feel free to ask it separately. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site, including [our 27 other questions about Noah's flood](/questions/tagged/mabul). You may wish to [register](/users/login) your account for [more site features](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557).

Comment: Presumably it's not to be read that hyper-literally according to that opinion, as I suspect you could have guessed.